# DrawerNavigator - Can't open DrawerNavigator inside StackNavigator route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

recently I have a problem on a simple DrawerNavigator inside StackNavigator. **My goal is** to get both the **back function from StackNavigator** and **DrawerNavigator side menu** when I click BurgerMenu icon on the StackNavigator's header.

Here's my current code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import SideBar from './SideBar';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen3';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <StackNav />;
  }
}

class BurgerMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
                  <TouchableHighlight 
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
                    <SvgUri
                      width="30"
                      height="30"
                      source={require("Project_01/app/images/menu.svg")}
                    />
                  </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1 }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);

const StackNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: {
      screen: DrawerNav,
    },
    Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
    },
    Screen3: {
      screen: Screen3,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'DrawerNav',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerRight: <BurgerMenu /> ,
      title: "Header"
    },
  },
);
```

As you can see Im adding headerRight with BurgerMenu component to navigationOptions in StackNavigator.

In BurgerMenu class I added TouchableHighlight with " onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}> " which I mean open up the DrawerNavigator.

Unfortunately when I press that, i got an error message says "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.props.navigation.navigate').

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
    navigationOptions: {
      headerRight: <BurgerMenu /> ,
      title: "Header"
    },
```

by this:

```
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    headerRight: <BurgerMenu navigation={navigation} />,
    title: "Header"
  }),
```

Also you can refer to this  [example](https://github.com/YanNerio/react-drawer-tabs-navigation) on my github.

Comment: Hi @Yanci Nerio !:). Thanks for ur example, but I still need my code to do work. My plan was open the drawer when Im on 'Screen2'. I did what u said by replacing those 'navigationOptions' and ending up back to Screen one. What I want is to stay on Screen2 while open up the drawer. How do I achieve that?